# Saddle-node bifurcation Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems, partial-derivative, bifurcation

I am working through the Taylor expansion of $\dot{x}=f(x,r)$ at $x=x^*$ and $r=r_c$ in Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos (Strogatz) [Saddle-Node Bifurcations]:

\begin{align}
\dot{x} & = f(x,r) \\
 & = f(x^{*},r_c)+(x-x^{*}) \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}\Bigg|_{(x^{*},r_c)} +(r-r_c)\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{r}}\Bigg|_{(x^{*},r_c)}+\frac{1}{2}(x-x^{*})^2\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}\Bigg|_{(x^{*},r_c)}+\ldots
\end{align}

The book says

> $f(x^{*},r_c)=0$ since $x^{*}$ is a fixed point, and
>   $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}\Big|_{(x^{*},r_c)}=0$ by the tangency
>   condition of a saddle-node bifurcation.

I understand $\dot{x}=f(x^{*},r_c)=0$ because it's at a fixed point.

What I don't understand is why $\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}\Big|_{(x^{*},r_c)}=0$. Isn't that the *stability* of the fixed point which can be $f'(x^{*})<0$, $f'(x^{*})>0$, or $f'(x^{*})=0$?

Comment: This condition is part of the [definition of a saddle-node bifurcation.](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Saddle-node_bifurcation)

Comment: +1 to @MichaelLee , and don't forget that linear terms tell something about stability only in hyperbolic case when Jacobi matrix has no eigenvalues on imaginary axis. In case of 1d ODE it translates to non-zero first derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $\textbf{Example $3.1.2$}$ on page $47$ in your book $\textit{Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos}$ by Steven H. Strogatz.

The example goes as follows: consider $\dot{x}=f(x,r)$, where your $f(x,r)=r-x-e^{-x}$. First, you want to find fixed points $x^*$, which occur when $f(x,r)=0$.

It is easier to plot $g(x,r)=r-x$ and $h(x)=e^{-x}$ on a graph and then visually look for the points of intersection, which are precisely the fixed points $x^*$. The $x$-axis on the graph remains the same while the $y$-axis represents $\dot{x}$, and we view $r$ as a constant for the time-being. There are two points of intersection as you can see below (photo credit: Figure $3.1.6 (a)$ on page $48$ in Strogatz):

[image]

Now, when you decrease the parameter $r$, the line corresponding to the function $g(x,r)$ will move down. When this line is tangent to the curve defined by $h(x)$, you get one fixed point and this fixed point is defined to be a $\textbf{saddle-node bifurcation}$, and such $r=r_c$ is defined to be a $\textbf{bifurcation point}$. Note that if you continue to decrease $r$, then the line will no longer intersect the curve and thus, there aren't any fixed points.

Now, returning to the saddle-node bifurcation, we obtain the bifurcation point $r_c$ precisely when:

1. the graphs $g(x,r)$ and $h(x)$ intersect, and
2. the tangent line of $g(x,r)$ is the tangent line of $h(x)$ at $x^*$.

Mathematically, the conditions are given by 
$$
r_c - x^*=e^{-{x^*}} \hspace{4mm}\mbox{ and } \hspace{4mm}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(r-x)\Bigg|_{(x^*,r_c)} = \frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x})\Bigg|_{(x^*,r_c)}, 
$$
and we can rewrite the equalities as: 
$$
r_c-x^*-e^{-{x^*}}=0\hspace{4mm} \mbox{ and }\hspace{4mm}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(r-x-e^{-x})\Bigg|_{(x^*,r_c)}=0. 
$$
These are equivalent to the conditions 
$$
f(x^*, r_c)=0 \hspace{4mm} \mbox{ and }\hspace{4mm} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,r)\Bigg|_{(x^*,r_c)}=0. 
$$